# Print array key = value with colon separating

Tags: tcl

I suspect there is a one liner that takes an array into a string which looks like x=1;y=2;z=3. How can I do that? I am currently using

```
set vals [join [array names a] \;]
```

to get x;y;z but would like the values in there. If there happens not to be a value, I would like to skip the = sign, e.g., x=1;y;z=3. Maybe with array get?

This gets all the info in there, but the result looks like x;1;y;2;z;3;q;3

```
set vals [join [array get a] \;]
```

some how I'm thinking there is a slice we can take here

**Update.** Yes, I know that you could do a foreach, but I wonder if there is a one-liner. For example this seems to work

```
foreach { k v } [array get a] {
  if {$v ne ""} {
    lappend valList $k=$v
  } else {
    lappend valList $k
  }
}
set vals [join $valList \;]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
join [lmap {k v} [array get a] {if {$v ne {}} {join [list $k $v] =} {set k}}] \;
```

If your Tcl doesn't have `lmap`, there's a handy [replacement](http://wiki.tcl.tk/40570).